# how to implement post in retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have a login screen that take the username and password from user and validate it in the backend. Code i have written so far is below

```
package com.example.opinion;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.Map;


import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;

import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.POST;


public class Login extends Activity {
    private Button login;
    private Button reg;
    private EditText uname;
    private EditText pword;

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.0.105/";

    public interface LoginApi{
        @POST("login")
        Call<HttpBinResponse> userLogin(@Body LoginData data);
    }


    static class HttpBinResponse {

        String result;
    }

    public class LoginData {
        String username;
        String password;

        public LoginData(String uname, String pword) {
            this.username = uname;
            this.password = pword;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        login =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
         reg =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnregister);


         uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.uname);
         pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);



         login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String name = uname.getText().toString();
                String pass = pword.getText().toString();

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
                LoginData user = new LoginData(name, pass);
                System.out.println(user.username+user.password);
                LoginApi apiService = retrofit.create(LoginApi.class);
                Call<HttpBinResponse> call = apiService.userLogin(user);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<HttpBinResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<HttpBinResponse> call, Response<HttpBinResponse> response) {
                        int statusCode = response.code();

                        HttpBinResponse decodedResponse = response.body();
                        if (decodedResponse == null)
                            return;

                        // at this point the JSON body has been successfully parsed
                        System.out.println(decodedResponse.result);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<HttpBinResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    }


                });
                Intent it= new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
                startActivity(it);




            }
        });

         reg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Intent it = new Intent(Login.this, Registration.class);
                 startActivity(it);


             }
         });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```

In the above code LoginData class is used to attach the body for my post request. 
HttpBinResponse class is for getting the response and store it in the result attribute. But i checked that my code is not returning any thing as the decodedResponse.result is null.

see this:

> 05-30 11:35:59.186  31176-31194/? I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL,
>   version 1.4 05-30 11:36:08.783  31176-31176/com.example.opinion
>   I/System.out﹕ hkbffghjk 05-30 11:36:08.877 
>   31176-31176/com.example.opinion I/System.out﹕ null

instead of null it should be a json object with key as result and its value.
Can anyone tell me how to get the proper response.

it seems like the url i'm creating is not created properly, either the body of the post request is not getting attached or some other problem.

i checked my sever logs and found that the request is reaching the server but nothing happens after that.

Comment: Please describe your problem.  "Not running properly" does not tell us what is happening or how to help you.  If you're getting an error message, post it.  If you're not, look up how to do logging with retrofit.

Comment: I can not connect to http://192.168.0.105/ ?